# Ng server - Angular server ist not starting

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to learn Angular from Youtube-Tutorial. I installed Node.JS and Angular and already created a project. I can open and edit the projects file. But I can not start the server, if I am in the folder with the console and try "`ng serve`" or "`ng serve --open`", the console makes a line break and does something, but even after a long time waiting, nothing happens and I also can not reach the server under "localhost:4200"

I use Windows 10, ng version: 12.14.1 , npm version: 6.13.6, Angular version: 8.3.22

EDIT: 
It turns out that the server is starting, but it takes around 10-15 minutes for an empty project to be compiled and to be started. I have a Intel Core i5 and 8GB of RAM.

Comment: please check node_module folder is exits on your project. if not run npm install first. if both is ok tell your detailed problem with error shown on console.

Comment: @Martin once try ng serve --source-map=false

Comment: have a look at this article https://dev.to/marcel_cremer/a-simple-tip-to-improve-angulars-compilation-speed-5dm0

Comment: run `ng --version` and post the output here.

Comment: The "node_module"-folder is existing

Comment: "ng serve --source-map=false" does not help

Comment: It turned out that it just takes a long time to start the server (around 10-15 minutes) for an empty project. I have a Intel Core i5 and 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) guide and you should be good to go. it could be that you did not install it globally try this command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I installed it globally (I think I did so before, and it did not solve the problem)